# Handle data from file having big size in java

Tags: java

I have file filled with text lines. File's size is about 150GB. What **the best solution** to sort all of the lines by alphabet? For example:

**INPUT:**

> We’re pretty sure someone famous once said that.
>  breathe in the
>   millennial generation.
>  Anyway, It’s the phrase that we live by
>   here at Alphabet.
>  have an unrivalled energy and passion for
>   creating brands that live and

**OUTPUT:**

> Anyway, It’s the phrase that we live by here at Alphabet.
>  breathe
>   in the millennial generation.
>  have an unrivalled energy and
>   passion for creating brands that live and
>  We’re pretty sure
>   someone famous once said that.

Comment: "'Begin at the beginning,' the King said, very gravely, 'and go on till you come to the end: then stop.'" -Lewis Carroll

Comment: One line at a time, via `BufferedReader.readLine()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We usually don’t need all of the lines in the file in memory at once – instead, we just need to be able to iterate through each one, do some processing and throw it away. So, this is exactly what we’re going to do – iterate through the lines without holding the in memory.

```
FileInputStream inputStream = null;
Scanner sc = null;
try {
    inputStream = new FileInputStream(path);
    sc = new Scanner(inputStream, "UTF-8");
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        // System.out.println(line);
    }
    // note that Scanner suppresses exceptions
    if (sc.ioException() != null) {
        throw sc.ioException();
    }
} finally {
    if (inputStream != null) {
        inputStream.close();
    }
    if (sc != null) {
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

This solution will iterate through all the lines in the file – allowing for processing of each line – without keeping references to them – and in conclusion, without keeping them in memory. http://www.baeldung.com/java-read-lines-large-file